# Learning graphical programming (i.e. game programming)?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm a pretty competent programmer, finishing my second year in university.
I am well versed in C and Java, and know a little Python as well.

However I've always wanted to create games. I don't know if thats the job I will end up having, but its definitely a hobby I want to be able to pursue.

When i look at the task of creating a 3d game (a non-trivial one), I believe I could create the 'engine' for the game. That is, the underlying code which controls the function of the game.

However, I have no idea how to create the graphics.

So my question to the community is what would be an appropriate place to start learning this?

Are there any good tutorials or sites to visit which assume I'm working with little previous knowledge?

Also, suggestions for perhaps a quicker method of creating the graphics would be appreciated. For example, i understand opengl has quite the learning curve (correct me if I'm wrong), and as a hobbyist, I'd like to see results sooner rather then later. However if there is a really thorough opengl tutorial, then that would be great too.

Thanks!

Comment: you could also ask at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: man, so many stackexchange sites I don't know about!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174830/learning-game-programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to learn OpenGL, go straight to the source:

http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/

Decide what you want in your engine, and a quick search in the red book will tell you what you need to do and how to do it. It's an amazing reference that EVERY OpenGL programmer should have.

And if you don't want to buy it, they have older (but still useful!) versions on the web (at the link I posted.)

I actually have two copies of it because (when I was doing OpenGL) I used it that much I needed at work and home.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [XNA](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/) for an easy yet powerful way into game programming. You get the benefits of C# and .NET, with access to DirectX functionality without having to delve into the lowest layers of implementation.

If you really want to go 3D, you should start by learning to use an existing engine, like [Ogre 3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/) or start playing with the [Unreal Development Kit](http://www.udk.com/) or [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).

It all depends on your objectives. My advice is to start small (think Pong, Breakout, Tetris, etc...) before tackling bigger games.

Comment: Yep, i figured small games first, and then build up from there. 
I'll look into XNA. While opengl is nice, it seems too low-level from what I would like, only because I don't want to spend a lot of time learning.